# как избавиться от ошибки ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT при запуске службы?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-service

Товарищи помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой запуска службы Windows. При попытке запуска выдаёт ошибку - ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, не могу понять как с этим бороться. Службу писал по примеру из книги Побегайло.

Исходники службы:

```
#include "windowsservicetest.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

QString protocolFileName;

void messageToFile(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString& msg) {

  if (protocolFileName.isEmpty()) {
      protocolFileName = "defaultJournal";
  }

  QFile file(protocolFileName);
  if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text | QIODevice::Append)) {
      return;
  }

  QTextStream out(&file);

  switch (type) {
  case QtDebugMsg:
      out << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss:zzz") << " Debug: " << msg << ",     " << context.file << "     " << context.function << endl;
      break;
  case QtWarningMsg:
      out << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss:zzz") << " Warning: " << msg << ",      " << context.file << endl;
      break;
  case QtCriticalMsg:
      out << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss:zzz") << " Critical: " << msg << ",  " << context.file << endl;
      break;
  case QtFatalMsg:
      out << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss:zzz") << " Fatal: " << msg << ",     " << context.file << endl;
      break;
  }
  file.close();
}

char service_name[] = "DemoService";

SERVICE_STATUS service_status;
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE hServiceStatus;

VOID WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD dwArgc, LPTSTR* lpszArgv);
VOID WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD dwControl);

std::ofstream  out;
int nCount;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  protocolFileName = "d:\\log.log";
  qInstallMessageHandler(messageToFile);


  SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY service_table[] = {
      {service_name, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain},
      {NULL, NULL}
  };

  if (!StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(service_table)) {

      qDebug() << "StartServiceCtrlDispatcher failed"<<endl<<"The error is: "<<GetLastError()<<endl;
      return 0;
  }
}

VOID WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD dwArgc, LPTSTR* lpszArgv) {

    hServiceStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(service_name, ServiceCtrlHandler);

    if (!hServiceStatus) {
        qDebug() << "Register service control handler failed";
        return;
    }

    service_status.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    service_status.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
    service_status.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;
    service_status.dwWin32ExitCode = ERROR_SERVICE_SPECIFIC_ERROR;
    service_status.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    service_status.dwCheckPoint = 0;
    service_status.dwWaitHint = 5000;

    if (!SetServiceStatus(hServiceStatus, &service_status)) {
        qDebug() << "Set service status 'SERVICE_START_PENDING' failed";
        return;
    }

    service_status.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
    service_status.dwWin32ExitCode = NO_ERROR;

    if (!SetServiceStatus(hServiceStatus, &service_status)) {
        qDebug() << "Set service status 'START_PENDING' failed";
        return;
    }

    qDebug() << "The service is started";
    qDebug() << "My name is: " << lpszArgv[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < (int)dwArgc; i++) {
        qDebug() << "My " << i << " parameter = " << lpszArgv[i];
    }

    while (service_status.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING) {
        nCount++;
        qDebug() << "Counter = " << nCount;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

VOID WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD dwControl) {

    switch (dwControl) {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:

        qDebug() << "The service is finished";
        qDebug() << "Current counter value is: " << nCount;

        service_status.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
        SetServiceStatus(hServiceStatus, &service_status);
        break;

    case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:

        service_status.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
        SetServiceStatus(hServiceStatus, &service_status);
        break;

    default:
        ++service_status.dwCheckPoint;
        SetServiceStatus(hServiceStatus, &service_status);
        break;
    }

    return;
}
```

Исходники установщика службы:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    SC_HANDLE hServiceControlManager, hService;

    hServiceControlManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);
    if (hServiceControlManager == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Open service control manager failed" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The last error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Press any key to exit" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Service controle manager is opened" << std::endl<<"Press any key to continue"<<std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    hService = CreateService(
        hServiceControlManager,
        "DemoService",
        "Demo_Service",
        SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,
        SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
        SERVICE_DEMAND_START,
        SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
        //"e:\\QTVS\\WindowsServiceTest\\Win32\\Debug\\WindowsServiceTest.exe",
        "D://WindowsServiceTest.exe",
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );

    if (!hService) {
        std::cout << "Create service failed" << std::endl
            << "The last error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl
            << "Press any key to exit" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();

        CloseServiceHandle(hServiceControlManager);
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Service is installed" << std::endl << "Press any key to exit" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    CloseServiceHandle(hService);
    CloseServiceHandle(hServiceControlManager);

    return 0;
}
```

исходники открытия и запуска службы:

```
// StartWindowsService.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char service_name[] = "DemoService";
    char *param[] = { "p1", "p2", "p3" };
    SC_HANDLE hServiceControleManager, hService;
    SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS ssStatus;
    DWORD dwOldCheckPoint;
    DWORD dwStartTickCount;
    DWORD dwWaitTime;
    DWORD dwBytesNeeded;

    hServiceControleManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);

    if (hServiceControleManager == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Open service controle manager failed" << std::endl << "The last error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl<<"Press any key to exit";
        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Service controle manager is opened" << std::endl << "Press any key to continue" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    hService = OpenService(hServiceControleManager, service_name, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);

    if (hService == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Open service failed" << std::endl << "The last error is: " << GetLastError() << std::endl << "Press any key to continue" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        CloseServiceHandle(hServiceControleManager);
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Service is opened" << std::endl << "Press any key to continue" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();


    if (!QueryServiceStatusEx(
        hService,                     // handle to service 
        SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,         // information level
        (LPBYTE)&ssStatus,             // address of structure
        sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS), // size of structure
        &dwBytesNeeded))              // size needed if buffer is too small
    {
        printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseServiceHandle(hService);
        CloseServiceHandle(hServiceControleManager);
        return 0;
    }

    // Check if the service is already running. It would be possible 
    // to stop the service here, but for simplicity this example just returns. 

    if (ssStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOPPED && ssStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    {
        printf("Cannot start the service because it is already running\n");
        CloseServiceHandle(hService);
        CloseServiceHandle(hServiceControleManager);
        return 0;
    }

    // Save the tick count and initial checkpoint.

    dwStartTickCount = GetTickCount();
    dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;

    // Wait for the service to stop before attempting to start it.

    while (ssStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    {
        // Do not wait longer than the wait hint. A good interval is 
        // one-tenth of the wait hint but not less than 1 second  
        // and not more than 10 seconds. 

        dwWaitTime = ssStatus.dwWaitHint / 10;

        if (dwWaitTime < 1000)
            dwWaitTime = 1000;
        else if (dwWaitTime > 10000)
            dwWaitTime = 10000;

        Sleep(dwWaitTime);

        // Check the status until the service is no longer stop pending. 

        if (!QueryServiceStatusEx(
            hService,                     // handle to service 
            SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,         // information level
            (LPBYTE)&ssStatus,             // address of structure
            sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS), // size of structure
            &dwBytesNeeded))              // size needed if buffer is too small
        {
            printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
            CloseServiceHandle(hService);
            CloseServiceHandle(hServiceControleManager);
            return 0;
        }

        if (ssStatus.dwCheckPoint > dwOldCheckPoint)
        {
            // Continue to wait and check.

            dwStartTickCount = GetTickCount();
            dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;
        }
        else
        {
            if (GetTickCount() - dwStartTickCount > ssStatus.dwWaitHint)
            {
                printf("Timeout waiting for service to stop\n");
                CloseServiceHandle(hService);
                CloseServiceHandle(hServiceControleManager);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }



    if (!StartService(hService, 3, (const char**)param)) {
        std::cout << "Start service failed" << std::endl << "The last error is: " << GetLastError() << std::endl << "Press any key to exit" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();

        CloseServiceHandle(hService);
        CloseServiceHandle(hServiceControleManager);
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Service is started" << std::endl << "Press any key to exit" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    CloseServiceHandle(hService);
    CloseServiceHandle(hServiceControleManager);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вообще эта ошибка означает, что ваша служба не вызвала StartServiceCtrlDispatcher либо та зависла (например, заблокирована) при выполнении. Разбираться в коде не охота, попробуйте сами посмотреть на него под этим углом - где что могло заблочить вызов StartServiceCtrlDispatcher.

Comment: на семерке заработало без проблем, а на 10 работает только если изменить параметры входа с системной учетной записи на локальную и мне это не понятно